# htaccess querystring redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a large amount of pages that have added random numbers onto the end of the page urls, I need to redirect these pages to a single url but there will be a large amount of urls throughout the website e.g.;

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50134.html

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50140.html

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50145.html

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50168.html

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50384.html

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50393.html

http://www.domain.com/a002-product-ring-50404.html

These need redirecting to http://www.domain.com/a002.html but the only thing i need to query is the number so something like this is what I thought would work;

```
Redirect 301 /a002-product-ring-(*).html http://www.domain.com/a002.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` for regex capabilities:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 (a.+?)-product-ring-[^.]+\.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1.html
```

Comment: That didn't work, I have noticed that there is a word infront of the product on some urls so the url to redirect is

http://www.domain.com/design-a002-product-ring-50393.html but it is not redirecting currently

Answer (score 0):

We can use RewriteCond and match the uri pattern as following.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(hello.html|contact_us.php)$

RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.domain.com/a002.html [R=302,L]